# ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2. Raise value error while I use scaler.inverse_transform()

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, lstm, valueerror

I'm trying to implement this code to predict a future stock price. The code seems to work well the error raise while I run the last line of the code:

```
predicted_stock_price = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
```

Below I add the entire code:

```
import pandas_datareader as web
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout

ticker = "AAPL"

while True:
    data_inizio = str(input("data d'inizi dell'analisi (inserisci giorno mese ed anno): " ))
    try:
        start1 = datetime.strptime(data_inizio, '%d %m %Y')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('il formato inserito non è corretto scrivere la data inserendo giorno mese ed anno separati dallo spazio es. 20 01 2021')

while True:
    data_fine = str(input("data di fine analisi (inserisci giorno mese ed anno): " ))
    try:
        end1 = datetime.strptime(data_fine, '%d %m %Y')
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('il formato inserito non è corretto scrivere la data inserendo giorno mese ed anno separati dallo spazio es. 20 01 2021')

inizio_analisi = start1
fine_analisi = end1


dati_finanziari_ticker = web.DataReader(ticker, data_source="yahoo", start=inizio_analisi, end=fine_analisi)
periodo_analisi = dati_finanziari_ticker.shape[0]
periodo_allenamento_programma = round(periodo_analisi*0.8)
periodo_test_programma = periodo_analisi
dati_finanziari_ticker_scalati = dati_finanziari_ticker.iloc[:, 3:4].values


scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
dati_allenamento_scalati = scaler.fit_transform(dati_finanziari_ticker_scalati)


X_allenamento = [] 
y_allenamento = []

for i in range(60, periodo_allenamento_programma):
  X_allenamento.append(dati_finanziari_ticker_scalati[i-60:i, 0])
  y_allenamento.append(dati_finanziari_ticker_scalati[i,0])


X_allenamento, y_allenamento = np.array(X_allenamento), np.array(y_allenamento)
X_allenamento = np.reshape(X_allenamento, (X_allenamento.shape[0], X_allenamento.shape[1], 1))

#LSTM
model1 = Sequential()

model1.add(LSTM(70, activation = "relu", return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_allenamento.shape[1], 1)))
model1.add(Dropout(0.2))

model1.add(LSTM(90, activation = "relu", return_sequences = True))
model1.add(Dropout(0.3))

model1.add(LSTM(120, activation = "relu", return_sequences = True))
model1.add(Dropout(0.4))

model1.add(LSTM(150, activation = "relu", return_sequences = True))
model1.add(Dropout(0.6))

model1.add(Dense(1))

model1.summary

model1.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "mean_squared_error")

model1.fit(X_allenamento, y_allenamento, epochs=10, batch_size=28)

#CREAZIONE DEGLI ARRAY PER IL TEST
X_test = [] 
y_test = []

for i in range(periodo_allenamento_programma, periodo_test_programma):
  X_test.append(dati_finanziari_ticker_scalati[i-60:i, 0])
  y_test.append(dati_finanziari_ticker_scalati[i,0])


X_test, y_test = np.array(X_test), np.array(y_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))


predicted_stock_price = model1.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
```

That's the entire error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-224-dacdc53f9aa9> in <module>
      1 #PREDIZIONE
      2 predicted_stock_price = model1.predict(X_test)
----> 3 predicted_stock_price = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
      4 
      5 #nsamples, nx, ny = predicted_stock_price.shape

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
    524 
    525         X = check_array(
--> 526             X, copy=self.copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES, force_all_finite="allow-nan"
    527         )
    528 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    794             raise ValueError(
    795                 "Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."
--> 796                 % (array.ndim, estimator_name)
    797             )
    798 

ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

I've tried to reshape the array, but probably I've done it bad because it didn't work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleve your scaler applies to the whole dataframe on which you build `X` and `Y` right ? I would make a scaler for the X values and one for the Y values if necessary in each case, so maybe operate on the `numpy` data

I would also recommend you to fit on the train dataset, in order to remove any use of the test dataset in the training process.

Thus I would do:

```
scaler_target = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
Y_allamento = scaler.fit_transform(Y_allenamento)
```

And then:

```
predicted_stock_price = model1.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)
```

Here I removed the `X` scaling, but you can put it if you want

Comment: So you're suggesting me to scale the arrays X_allenamento and y_allenamento after the for cycle. I'm sorry if I haven't understood well but I'm a beginner. Anyway thanks for your help

Comment: @FrancescoStocchi Yes, but the important is that this way you apply on the training part only. Also be aware of what your scaler takes as data, the target or the features